# Breakpoints does not work in Firefox (19.0) using Firebug(1.11.2)

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>An example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function User(id) {
                this.id = id;
            };
            var bob = new User(32);

            var jack = new User(bob.id); 
            jack.id = 100;   // Set a breakpoint here, but it does not stop here
            alert('end of test' + jack.id);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

BTW, the breakpoints works normally in chrome.

I am confused... This should be a very simple example. Is this a bug of Firefox ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the console display any errors?

Comment: No error is found on console. The alert in the last line works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug of firebug. Adding a new line before the last statement seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I've also reproduced it. Seems to be a bug.

Some notes however:

1. Generally it's recommended to minimize the execution of JavaScript directly like you're doing it, but defer it after page load. E.g. you can wrap everything in a function called `init` and then use `addEventListener` / `attachListener` to the `load` event (or write `<body onload="init()">`). Executing JS as-you-go in the HTML slows down the rendering of the page; all the JS must be parsed and executed, because potentially it might add some HTML elements dynamically which will alter the rendering of the HTML later on the page. So avoid computation-heavy and long scripts added to the page in this way.
2. You can also wrap your code in so-called IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression):

   ```javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        function User(id) {
            this.id = id;
        };
        var bob = new User(32);

        var jack = new User(bob.id); 
        jack.id = 100;   // Set a breakpoint here, but it does not stop here
        alert('end of test' + jack.id);
    })();
    </script>
   ```

   In that case, Firebug properly executes breakpoints.
3. Note that the line numbers 13 and 14 are not marked in green in the code listing in Firebug. This is the information from Firebug that no breakpoints will hit if you put it in this line. In most cases, it means there's no JavaScript in that line (e.g.: HTML, empty line, comment etc.) but sometimes it's due to a bug in Firebug.